# Is there a better way to test for a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception, coded-ui-tests

The application is running and the window of the application is visible on the screen, 
but the coded ui test always gets a NullReferenceException:

- sampling = application
- sampling.Window = main window of the application

Code:

```
if(object.ReferenceEquals(sampling, null)) // sampling is not a null reference (debug output)
if(sampling == null) //  sampling is not null
if(object.ReferenceEquals(sampling.Window, null)) //  sampling.Window is not a null reference
if(sampling.Window == null) //  sampling.Window is not null
if (sampling.Window.Exists) //  sampling.Window exists? True
if(sampling.Window.TryGetClickablePoint(out pt)) //  Got clickable point? False  Point = {X=0,Y=0}

if(object.ReferenceEquals(sampling.Window.BoundingRectangle, null)) //  Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if(object.ReferenceEquals(sampling.Window.ControlType, null)) //  Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if(object.ReferenceEquals(sampling.Window.Name, null)) //  Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if(object.ReferenceEquals(sampling.Window.ClassName, null)) //  Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if(sampling.Window.BoundingRectangle == null) //   Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if(sampling.Window.ControlType == null) //   Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if(sampling.Window.Name == null) //   Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if(sampling.Window.ClassName == null) //   Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: You need to format your question better. Code should be formatted, exception stacks should be block quotes. You should also tag the question with what language you're using.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

If `sampling.Window` itself is *not* `null`, yet stuff like `sampling.Window.Name == null` leads to a `NullReferenceException`, I suspect the exception comes from inside the `get` accessor of the property `Name`.

Have you compiled this without optimizations (in "Debug" mode) and tried running it with the debugger of Visual Studio attached? It should halt execution when the exception occurs, and you should be able to see just which reference is `null`. It might be in the line just above the line Visual Studio highlights with a color.

Comment: Yes, I have compiled it in "debug" mode and debugged it several times . The problem is that there is no null reference.
The problem seems to be the launsching of the application:
root = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(Settings.Default.SamplingAppUrl);
The properties of root (ApplicationUnderTest object) e.g. HasTitleBar, Maximized etc. all throw a NullReferenceException.